# how to print name of newly created file(s) within a directory in C?

Tags: c, loops, inotify

This code scans for newly created files within a directory, however where "%s" should contain the name of the new file(s) this does not occur.

I can imagine there are unnecessary pieces of code written here, however being quite unfamiliar with C I'm simply happy it compiles at this point (and actually recognizes new files) !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char target[FILENAME_MAX];
        int result;
        int fd;
        int wd; /* watch descriptor */
        const int event_size = sizeof(struct inotify_event);
        const int buf_len = 1024 * (event_size + FILENAME_MAX);

        fd = inotify_init();

        if (fd < 0) {
                perror("inotify_init");
        }

        wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/home/joe/Documents", IN_CREATE);

        while (1) {
                char buff[buf_len];
                int no_of_events, count = 0;

                no_of_events = read (fd, buff, buf_len);

                while (count < no_of_events) {
                        struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&buff[count];

                        if (event->len) {
                                if (event->mask & IN_CREATE)
                                        if(!(event->mask & IN_ISDIR)) {
                                                printf("The file %s has been created\n", target);
                                                fflush(stdout);
                                        }
                        }
                        count += event_size + event->len;
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler (gcc) to output lots of warnings about implicit type conversions and about unused variables.  It also discusses where the variable `wd` is set but never used.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing out `target` when you get an event, however `target` is never modified.

The name of the created file is stored in `event->name`.  That's what you want to print.

```
printf("The file %s has been created\n", event->name);
```